# Is it possible to find a basis of vectors orthogonal to a given vector with an extra constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider a $N-$dimensional complex vector $\mathbf{g}$. I know it is always possible to find an orthonormal basis of vectors $\{ \mathbf{d}_1, \mathbf{d}_2,...\mathbf{d}_{N-1}\}$ in the subspace orthogonal to $\mathbf{g}$, i.e. vectors that fulfill
$$
\mathbf{d}_i\cdot\mathbf{g}^*=0 \hspace{1cm}\forall i
$$
$$
\mathbf{d}_i\cdot \mathbf{d}_j^* = \delta_{ij}\hspace{1cm}\forall i,j
$$
with $\delta_{ij}$ the Kronecker delta. Clearly the above equations are underdetermined, i.e. there are multiple possible sets of vectors $\{\mathbf{d}_i\}$ fulfilling these equations. My question is, can one find an orthonormal basis $\{\mathbf{d}_i\}$ fulfilling the above equations *plus the additional constraint*
$$
\mathbf{d}_i\cdot \Omega \cdot \mathbf{d}_j^* = C_i\delta_{ij}
$$
with $\Omega$ a given diagonal matrix with distinct entries (i.e. not proportional to the identity matrix), and $C_i$ an arbitrary number? and if yes, is this last equation enough to fully determine all the vectors $\{\mathbf{d}_i\}$ or does some freedom to choose the vectors remain?

EDIT: Sorry for the original lack of clarity. Thanks to the comments I specified my question better.

EDIT 2: Here is an example where such a basis can be found. Consider $N=3$, $g=(1,0,0)$ and
$$
\Omega=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 &0
\\
0& 1 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 &A
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with $A\ne 1$.
The orthonormal basis $\mathbf{d}_1=(0,\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $\mathbf{d}_2 = (0,\sin\theta,-\cos\theta)$ fulfils the first two conditions above for all values of $\theta$. The additional condition $\mathbf{d}_i\cdot \Omega \cdot \mathbf{d}_j = \delta_{ij}$ is only fulfilled if $\sin\theta\cos\theta(1-A)=0$ or equivalently $\theta=n\pi/2$ with $n$ inteeger. So in this case it is possible to find a base fulfilling all three conditions.

My question would be: is this possible for arbitrary $\mathbf{g}$, an arbitrary diagonal matrix $\Omega$, and for arbitrary dimension $N$? I am not sure how to go about proving this...

Comment: What if, e.g., $\Omega=2\cdot\operatorname{id}$?

Comment: linguistically there is a problem in that you mention a subspace of vectors whose basis is  orthogonal to $g$ but then insist this is equivalent to being orthonormal, which is false -- normalization imposes additional constraints that are a distraction here (and generates the above counterexample).  More significantly: you should easily be able to find a counterexample when $N=2$ and $\mathbf g$ is the ones vector. Original posters are expected to show some work and 2-d example are well within this realm.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and sorry for the lack of clarity, I updated the question to improve clarity and add an example. Basically I am searching for an orthonormal basis and the matrix Omega is not arbitrary but a given diagonal matrix different from the identity. Do you have any insights on how to prove (if possible) that such a basis always exists? thanks!